Rice theorem - $EQ_{TM}$
Could use some help understanding if Rice’s theorem applies to the following language: $ = \{\langle \rangle \lvert M \text{     } () \subseteq _{TM} \}$ (where $EQ_{TM} =\{\langle M,N\rangle| M,N \text{ are TMs and } L(M)= L(N)\} $ EQ is in none to my understanding)
My first intuition is no, because C (the property) is not exactly a property of a language. If this is indeed false then I should be able to construct two TMs that have the same language but only one of them belongs to L (struggling with that)

Please define $EQ_{TM}$.

Yes, you can apply Rice' Theorem. You need that $L$ is of the form
$$ L = \{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M)\in U \}$$
Where $U$ is a proper, nonempty subset of the r.e. languages. (In this case we say the $U$ is not trivial.) In your case we have that
$$U = \{ L \mid \text{$L$ is r.e. und $L \subseteq EQ_{TM}$ }\}$$
No Matter how you did the encoding in $EQ_{TM}$ this set is not $\Sigma^*$. It follows that $\emptyset$ is in $U$, but $\Sigma^*$ is not in $U$. Thus, $U$ has the tow required properties (proper subset because $\Sigma^*$ is missing, not empty because it contains $\emptyset$).

You seem to have a hard time understanding what it means for a language to be semantic.
Formally

A language $L$ is semantic, if for TMs $M_1, M_2$ with $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$ holds $\langle M_1 \rangle \in L \iff \langle M_2 \rangle \in L$.

But intuitively, this only means something like this

A language $L$ is semantic, if whether $\langle M \rangle \in L$ depends only on $L(M)$, not of $M$ itself.

Your language for example is semantic, because whether $\langle M \rangle \in L$ is decided only by $L(M) \subseteq EQ_{TM}$, it doesn't really matter what $M$ looks like.
You can also show this using the definition, assume $M_1, M_2$ are TMs with $L(M_1) = L(M_2)$.
Then either $L(M_1) = L(M_2) \subseteq EQ_{TM}$ or $L(M_1) = L(M_2) \nsubseteq EQ_{TM}$.
Now, is it possible for only one of $\langle M_1 \rangle, \langle M_2 \rangle$ to be in $L$?

Thank you for your response. I didn’t say anything about semantics. This is confusing me even more. I just want to know if Rice is applicable here or not. I guess I learned things differently

@user169627 Rices theorem applies, only if a language is both non-trivial and semantic (in the sense above).
I'm not sure if using the term "semantic" is standard , but it's the property you were trying to refute.

Oh I see. So you are saying my initial thought is incorrect? Can you please show how $C = {L \lvert L \subseteq EQ_{TM} }$, $C \subseteq RE$ and $C \neq RE$? To formally (and shortly) prove Rice holds here I need to show 3 things: 1. C Non-trivial, 2. $C \subseteq RE$ 3. $C \neq RE$

I'm not sure what you're asking for makes sense, $C = \mathcal{P}(EQ_{TM})$ isn't countable while $RE$ is.
So it's impossible that $C \subseteq RE$.

Ok. So rice doesn’t hold. I’m even more confused now :(

No, that's not what I meant .
Rices theorem applies your language, at least all formulations that I'm aware of.

Ok. So, from what I know, to prove that the theorem holds we need to prove 1,2,3 that I wrote above

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
